# Show variantimage as clickable thumnail on collectionpage/home page Shopify (brooklyn Theme)

Tags: shopify

i'm trying to show all variants (only color) of a product as a thumbnail on the collectionpage below each product. I want the customer to be able to preview all variants in on collectionpage before going to productpage. Can someone help me with pointing in the richt direction.

What i have is the following. This outputs the variantnames and names of the images but not the thumbnails. What i want is the variant image attached to that variant name. Preferable able to preview on collectionpage on hover.

Thanks!

```html
<ul class="colorlist"> 
 {% for option in product.options %}
 {% if option == 'Color' %}
 {% assign index = forloop.index0 %}
 {% assign colorlist = '' %}
 {% assign color = '' %}
 {% for variant in product.variants %}
 {% capture color %}
 {{ variant.options[index] }}
 {% endcapture %}

 {% unless colorlist contains color %}
  {% if variant.available %}

  <li id="{{ variant.id }}" title="{{ variant.inventory_quantity }} In Stock" class="instock"><a href="{{ product.url | within: collection }}?variant={{ variant.id }}" style="background:{{ color | downcase }}">{{ color | downcase }}</a></li>

  {% else %}

  <li id="{{ variant.id }}" title="Out of Stock"  class="outstock" >{{ color | downcase }}</li>

  {% endif %}

{% capture tempList %}
{{colorlist | append: color | append: " " }} 
{% endcapture %}
{% assign colorlist = tempList %}
{{ product.selected_or_first_available_variant.featured_image }} 
{% endunless %}
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried other than looking for the answer to this problem?

Comment: Hi Drip, I currently investigated the internet for a code to place in a liquid file but what I find is different all the way. So I would like to know what to incorporate to get this working.